# MongoDb Cursor has been closed. Doesn't resume after db goes down

Tags: mongodb, production-environment, mongodb-java, spring-mongodb, changestream

There are millions of exceptions for cursor closed in our application.
**Cursor has been closed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: Cursor has been closed**

It happens when for a moment database server goes down and this cursor is never able to resume then forward.

[image]

Mongo java driver version is 3.8.2

Spring mongo version is 2.0.6.RELEASE.

We have registered
MessageListener<ChangeStreamDocument, T>
in our application.

Below are the mongo client properties that we have:

[image]

[image]

Not sure what is the cause of above issue. At the same time not sure whether there is some property that needs to be tuned to prevent this.

Below is the stack trace:

```
    MongoException.java in fromThrowableNonNull at line 79
    ChangeStreamBatchCursor.java in resumeableOperation at line 136
    ChangeStreamBatchCursor.java in tryNext at line 76
    MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java in tryNext at line 74
    CursorReadingTask.java in getNext at line 232
    CursorReadingTask.java in run at line 79
    Thread.java in run at line 748
```

```
    QueryBatchCursor.java in tryNext at line 174
    ChangeStreamBatchCursor.java in apply at line 79
    ChangeStreamBatchCursor.java in apply at line 76
    ChangeStreamBatchCursor.java in resumeableOperation at line 133
    ChangeStreamBatchCursor.java in tryNext at line 76
    MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java in tryNext at line 74
    CursorReadingTask.java in getNext at line 232
    CursorReadingTask.java in run at line 79
    Thread.java in run at line 748
```